# Flutter Draggable how to not insert data on hover?

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable, flutter-listview, dragtarget

[image: enter code here]

Im using drag target and draggable to create a drag and drop fill in the blanks. I was able to create drop the draggable to the correct drag target. How ever when i drag(Hover) another draggable over the the occupied drag target it either remove the occupied draggable or change the value on drag target. How can i prevent data changing on hover in drag target?..

Answer (score 0):

> **You can check the condition for empty items on Accept() of DragTarget Widget.**

```
  Widget _buildPersonWithDropZone(Customer customer) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 6.0,
        ),
        child: DragTarget<Item>(
          builder: (context, candidateItems, rejectedItems) {
            return CustomerCart(
              hasItems: customer.items.isNotEmpty,
              highlighted: candidateItems.isNotEmpty,
              customer: customer,
            );
          },
          onAccept: (item) {
            if (customer.items.isEmpty) {
              _itemDroppedOnCustomerCart(
                item: item,
                customer: customer,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> **Complete Code**

```
const List<Item> _items = [
  Item(
    name: 'Spinach Pizza',
    totalPriceCents: 1299,
    uid: '1',
    imageProvider: NetworkImage('https://flutter'
        '.dev/docs/cookbook/img-files/effects/split-check/Food1.jpg'),
  ),
  Item(
    name: 'Veggie Delight',
    totalPriceCents: 799,
    uid: '2',
    imageProvider: NetworkImage('https://flutter'
        '.dev/docs/cookbook/img-files/effects/split-check/Food2.jpg'),
  ),
  Item(
    name: 'Chicken Parmesan',
    totalPriceCents: 1499,
    uid: '3',
    imageProvider: NetworkImage('https://flutter'
        '.dev/docs/cookbook/img-files/effects/split-check/Food3.jpg'),
  ),
];

@immutable
class ExampleDragAndDrop extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleDragAndDrop({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleDragAndDrop> createState() => _ExampleDragAndDropState();
}

class _ExampleDragAndDropState extends State<ExampleDragAndDrop>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Customer> _people = [
    Customer(
      name: 'Makayla',
      imageProvider: const NetworkImage('https://flutter'
          '.dev/docs/cookbook/img-files/effects/split-check/Avatar1.jpg'),
    ),
    Customer(
      name: 'Nathan',
      imageProvider: const NetworkImage('https://flutter'
          '.dev/docs/cookbook/img-files/effects/split-check/Avatar2.jpg'),
    ),
    Customer(
      name: 'Emilio',
      imageProvider: const NetworkImage('https://flutter'
          '.dev/docs/cookbook/img-files/effects/split-check/Avatar3.jpg'),
    ),
  ];

  final GlobalKey _draggableKey = GlobalKey();

  void _itemDroppedOnCustomerCart({
    required Item item,
    required Customer customer,
  }) {
    setState(() {
      customer.items.add(item);
    });
  }

  void _itemRemovedFromCustomerCart({
    required Item item,
    required Customer customer,
  }) {
    setState(() {
      customer.items.removeAt(_items.length - 1);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF7F7F7),
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: _buildContent(),
    );
  }

  PreferredSizeWidget _buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFFF64209)),
      title: Text(
        'Order Food',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium?.copyWith(
              fontSize: 36,
              color: const Color(0xFFF64209),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF7F7F7),
      elevation: 0,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: _buildMenuList(),
              ),
              _buildPeopleRow(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMenuList() {
    return ListView.separated(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemCount: _items.length,
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return const SizedBox(
          height: 12.0,
        );
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final item = _items[index];
        return _buildMenuItem(
          item: item,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMenuItem({
    required Item item,
  }) {
    return LongPressDraggable<Item>(
      data: item,
      dragAnchorStrategy: pointerDragAnchorStrategy,
      feedback: DraggingListItem(
        dragKey: _draggableKey,
        photoProvider: item.imageProvider,
      ),
      child: MenuListItem(
        name: item.name,
        price: item.formattedTotalItemPrice,
        photoProvider: item.imageProvider,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPeopleRow() {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 8.0,
        vertical: 20.0,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: _people.map(_buildPersonWithDropZone).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPersonWithDropZone(Customer customer) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 6.0,
        ),
        child: DragTarget<Item>(
          builder: (context, candidateItems, rejectedItems) {
            return CustomerCart(
              hasItems: customer.items.isNotEmpty,
              highlighted: candidateItems.isNotEmpty,
              customer: customer,
            );
          },
          onAccept: (item) {
            if (customer.items.isEmpty) {
              _itemDroppedOnCustomerCart(
                item: item,
                customer: customer,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomerCart extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomerCart({
    super.key,
    required this.customer,
    this.highlighted = false,
    this.hasItems = false,
  });

  final Customer customer;
  final bool highlighted;
  final bool hasItems;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textColor = highlighted ? Colors.white : Colors.black;

    return Transform.scale(
      scale: highlighted ? 1.075 : 1.0,
      child: Material(
        elevation: highlighted ? 8.0 : 4.0,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),
        color: highlighted ? const Color(0xFFF64209) : Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 12.0,
            vertical: 24.0,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              ClipOval(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 46,
                  height: 46,
                  child: Image(
                    image: customer.imageProvider,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              Text(
                customer.name,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium?.copyWith(
                      color: textColor,
                      fontWeight:
                          hasItems ? FontWeight.normal : FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: hasItems,
                maintainState: true,
                maintainAnimation: true,
                maintainSize: true,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 4.0),
                    Text(
                      customer.formattedTotalItemPrice,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
                            color: textColor,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 4.0),
                    Text(
                      '${customer.items.length} item${customer.items.length != 1 ? 's' : ''}',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                            color: textColor,
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}

class MenuListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuListItem({
    super.key,
    this.name = '',
    this.price = '',
    required this.photoProvider,
    this.isDepressed = false,
  });

  final String name;
  final String price;
  final ImageProvider photoProvider;
  final bool isDepressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 12.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 120,
                height: 120,
                child: Center(
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                    curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                    height: isDepressed ? 115 : 120,
                    width: isDepressed ? 115 : 120,
                    child: Image(
                      image: photoProvider,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 30.0),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    name,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium?.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Text(
                    price,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium?.copyWith(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DraggingListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const DraggingListItem({
    super.key,
    required this.dragKey,
    required this.photoProvider,
  });

  final GlobalKey dragKey;
  final ImageProvider photoProvider;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FractionalTranslation(
      translation: const Offset(-0.5, -0.5),
      child: ClipRRect(
        key: dragKey,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: 0.85,
            child: Image(
              image: photoProvider,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

@immutable
class Item {
  const Item({
    required this.totalPriceCents,
    required this.name,
    required this.uid,
    required this.imageProvider,
  });

  final int totalPriceCents;
  final String name;
  final String uid;
  final ImageProvider imageProvider;

  String get formattedTotalItemPrice =>
      '\$${(totalPriceCents / 100.0).toStringAsFixed(2)}';
}

class Customer {
  Customer({
    required this.name,
    required this.imageProvider,
    List<Item>? items,
  }) : items = items ?? [];

  final String name;
  final ImageProvider imageProvider;
  final List<Item> items;

  String get formattedTotalItemPrice {
    final totalPriceCents =
        items.fold<int>(0, (prev, item) => prev + item.totalPriceCents);
    return '\$${(totalPriceCents / 100.0).toStringAsFixed(2)}';
  }
}
```